# Can't login to site

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to login to a site with Http apache client, using java and eclipse. I have tried many ways of writing the code, but it still does not work:

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

post = new HttpPost("http://www.biketrial.kiev.ua/forum/ucp.php?mode=login");

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

String login = new String(log.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String pas =new String(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",login ));

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pas));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

response = client.execute(post,localContext);

entity = response.getEntity();

BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));

String line="",ln="";

while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    ln+=line+"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The form tag has a unique component that changes every login attempt:

```
<form action="./ucp.php?mode=login&amp;sid=a1867e90f9f131fb99676a9db3892c95" method="post">
```

I don't know what else you may have to do, but at a minimum, I expect you need to load the login page and parse that action URL before attempting to post the credentials. Also, be aware that some administrators don't take kindly to automated systems connecting to sites intended for humans.